# Django multiple html paremeters

Tags: python, django, url-parameters

I'm trying to catch two parameters but I don't know how to send them via html.

This is the urls.py:

```
app_name = 'series'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<serie_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.season, name='season'),
    url(r'^(?P<serie_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<season_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.chapter, name='chapter'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

This is the html:

```
<ul>
{% for season in season_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'series:chapter' season.id %}">{{ season.season_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is the view:

```
def chapter (request, serie_id, season_id):
    season = Season.objects.get(pk=season_id)
    chapter_list = season.chapter_set.all()
    return render(request, 'series/serie.html', {'chapter_list': chapter_list})
```

I'm having this error:

```
Reverse for 'chapter' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'series/(?P<serie_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<season_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `urls.py`, you have two options for the URL:

Call `series:season` with just the series ID (`url(r'^(?P<serie_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.season, name='season')`):

```
<ul>
{% for season in season_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'series:season' series.id %}">{{ season.season_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

or call `series:chapter` (`url(r'^(?P<serie_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<season_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.chapter, name='chapter')`) with the series ID and season ID - I don't know where `series` comes from, so you need to modify this code before it will work.

```
<ul>
{% for season in season_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'series:chapter' series.id season.id %}">{{ season.season_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that I could pass multiple parameters like that.

Comment: @Lechucico, if this answer solves your problem, can you please mark it as correct?

Comment: I was going to do it, but a message appeared "you have to wait 2 hours before mark as answer".